# Analysis Service - Proactive caching failing

Tags: sql-server, caching, proactive

For a while the proactive caching process successfully sync the OLAP databse and then is starts giving the following error 'Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found:' followed by spesific data related information. I do not however have a problem if I manually process the databse with the 'Transactional Deployement' option set to True. I have set the data source isolation mode to snapshot and MARS connection setting to True on the connection string plus on the database side we have set the database property ALLOW SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION to ON and verified it. Can anyone help or give some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Your measure is being rebuilt and there is a key value not found in your dimension table (this is basically a race condition).

If data integrity is paramount, then you will need to do a full process of the cube.

If you can get away with some aggregates being off temporarily (or assigned to "Unknown" in the Dimension) then you can customize the Error Configuration to ignore errors or assign unknown keys to Unknown.  It should work itself out the next time the measure is rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a new dimension key was added - and used by your fact table.  The dimension key isn't in the cube yet, so it's not found when referenced by the fact...

This can happen quite easily, and is only fixed by a full reprocess (or if you're lucky, good timing of proactive caching on dimensions and facts).